Determine if a condition is ever true in an aggregated dataset with Scala spark sql library
I'm trying to aggregate a dataset and determine if a condition is ever true for a row in the dataset.
Suppose I have a dataset with these values



cust_id
travel_type
distance_travelled




1
car
10


1
boat
70


2
car
15


2
plane
600


3
boat
80


3
plane
100



I want to aggregate the dataset for each cust_id and determine if a certain condition was ever true for that id. For example, i want to determine if a customer took a flight with a distance greater than 500. The resulting data set should look like this



cust_id
hadLongDistanceFlight




1
false


2
true


3
false



The way I'm currently doing this is by collecting the results of a when evaluation to a set and later evaluating if a true value exists in the set. While it works, it makes the code very verbose and difficult to maintain as more conditions are added. Is there a way of doing this cleanly?
My current code looks something like this
myDataset.groupBy("cust_id").agg(
collect_set(
    when($"travel_type"==="plane" and $"distance_travelled" > 500), true).as("plane_set")
)
.withColumn("hadLongDistanceFlight", exists($"plane_set", _ === true))

I'm aware there is usually a bool_or function but it doesn't seem to exist in the Scala spark sql library. I'm using the 3.3.2 version of apache.spark.spark-sql and Scala 2.12.12

it can be written as next
myDataset
    .groupBy("cust_id")
    .agg(
      max(when($"travel_type" === "plane" and $"distance_travelled" > 500, true).otherwise(false)).as("hadLongDistanceFlight")
    )


count_if will do exactly that.  You can then compare the resulting count to zero.
> SELECT count_if(col % 2 = 0) FROM VALUES (NULL), (0), (1), (2), (3) AS tab(col);
 2
> SELECT count_if(col IS NULL) FROM VALUES (NULL), (0), (1), (2), (3) AS tab(col);
 1

The functions api for it is also count_if
If using expr is unwanted you can write your own count_if:
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.CountIf
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def count_if(predicate: Column): Column =
  new Column(CountIf(column.expr))


Hey, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I'm locked to spark version 3.3.2 and count_if was introduced in 3.5.x. Looks like a bool_or function was also introduced in 3.5.x. There might not be a cleaner solution for the version I'm using

you can use expr, the sql function was introduced in 3.0

@Darragh.McL I've added a forwarding api call for you if the dsl is preferred.  It's a bit internal and may change between Spark versions
